# How to test for mass assignment errors in Rspec and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently upgraded my Rails app from Rails 3 to 4 and this Rspec test is no longer passing:

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb:

require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  it "should not allow access to admin" do
    expect do
      User.new(:admin => true)
    end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
  end

end
```

I am getting this error:

```
Failure/Error: end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
```

I suspect that this is somehow due to the switch to Rails 4's **strong parameters**.

How can I test for mass assignment errors now?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: With strong params, this kind of test should be done at controller level, not model level.

Comment: @Baldrick: OK, so since I am already testing this in my controller tests, I can safely scrap the above test?

Comment: Yes. This article might convince you: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/

Comment: @Baldrick: I kind of had a hunch. Thanks for confirming this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Baldrick pointed out rightly there's no need in Rails 4 to test for mass assignment issues in Rspec model tests. The whole idea of Rails 4's [Strong Parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html) is to move all that functionality to the controller.

Answer (score 2):

To make your test pass you need add config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict to
config/aplication.rb  and add gem https://github.com/rails/protected_attributes to Gemfile.

If you want test strong parameters read this article http://pivotallabs.com/rails-4-testing-strong-parameters/